# Как сделать аббревиатуру в Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function isLetter(c) {
  return c.toLowerCase() !== c.toUpperCase()
}

function getAbbreviation(str) {
  return
}
console.log(getAbbreviation('some company name')) // ===> SCN
```

Должна быть проверка, чтобы в тексте были только буквы (уже есть функция isLetter())
Должна быть проверка, чтобы слово было не меньше 3 букв

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Что на входе? Что на выходе? Что значит что в тексте должны быть только буквы (у вас есть как минимум ещё и пробелы)? Добавьте больше деталей

Answer (score 1):

При входе строки с не подходящим словом "вылетает" ошибка. Поэтому обромляем в try/catch.
Проверка слова происходит при помощи [регулярного выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

```
const getAbbreviation = (str) => {
    return str.split(" ").map(e => {
        if ( (/^.{0,3}$|\d/).test(e) ) throw new Error("invalid word"); // Проверка слова
        return e[0].toUpperCase();
    }).join("");
}

try {
    console.log(getAbbreviation("some company name"));
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант:

```js
let text = 'some company name';
let abbr = text.replace(/\b(.+?)\b\s?/g, (m) => m[0].toUpperCase());
console.log(abbr);
```

Comment: Код выдает аббревиатуру для "s123 c123 n123" и для "s c n", что, вроде-бы, не должно работать. Хотя, автор не описал как такие случаи должны обрабатываться

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно что-то вроде такой реализации:

```
function isLetter(str) {
  const regExp = /[0-9]/
  if (!regExp.test(str) && str.length >= 3) {
    return str
  }
}


function getAbbreviation(str) {
  if (isLetter(str)) {
    return str.split(/\s+/).map(word => word[0].toUpperCase()).join('')
  } else {
    return 'Bad name'
  }
}

console.log(getAbbreviation('some company name'))  // SCN
console.log(getAbbreviation('other interesting name')) // OIN
console.log(getAbbreviation('1 2 3')) // Bad name
```

P.S. присоединяюсь к комментариям выше, вопрос непонятен и большую его часть я делал по собственным домыслам, старайтесь, пожалуйста, описывать вопрос конкретнее